# Serialize a list of primitives to XML with overrides

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an array of integers to XML, but I can't quite get the output to look the way I want.  I need to find some way to override the element name of each element in the array.
The code I have so far:

```
var numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(int[]), new XmlRootAttribute("rows"));
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, numbers);
    Console.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
}
```

The output I am after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <row>1</row>
  <row>2</row>
  <row>3</row>
  <row>4</row>
  <row>5</row>
</rows>
```

The current output that I see:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>3</int>
  <int>4</int>
  <int>5</int>
</rows>
```

Comment: If the int[] inside a class/struct then you can use XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute. It has "ElementName" property that you can set.

Comment: Yes, I could, but it isn't.  It is just a straight array / list (I can use either one) which needs to be serialized this way.  I would also prefer to be able to use the solution for arrays of other types as well, with the type determined at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a seperate class to hold your values and you can specify Xml attributes as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("rows")]
public class Rows
{
    [XmlElement("row")]
    public List<int> Elements { get; set; } 
}

public static void SerializeOnScreen()
{
    Rows numbers = new Rows();
    numbers.Elements = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rows));
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, numbers);
        Console.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
}
```